# What does Judaism say about lesbians?

Tags: sin, homosexuality

I noticed that all what was ever said about homosexuality was men homosexuality and their penalty, but I never heard about women homosexuality. I'm really curious as to why nothing has been said about it even though our sages (of blessed memory) didn't leave anything unanswered.

I happen to be a woman who was born attracted to other women, even though I never did it neither am I planning to pursue my desire due to my faith in Hashem. I know that a lot of people believe that it's impossible to be born as a homosexual, but I had it in my nature even before I entered school. I do remember some incidents that happened when I was only 4 years old concerning my attraction to women. The only thing I ever looked at was them while men never entered my mind even after I grew up.

I apologize if I offended anyone with my words, but I'm someone who is utterly disgusted with the men culture and it would be impossible for me to marry one. All the men that I ever encountered in my life only thought about sex and women's assets and their own pleasure, even if they tried to hide it it would still be obvious. Have they ever thought about pure love or is selfish pleasure all what's in their mind?

Is it so wrong that no matter how much I tried to consider men I still can't help but to be attracted to women?

I had recently come to terms where I realized that I don't really want to love men and I can't help but feel that I'm born to be thrown in hell for the way I was born and it honestly depresses me, even more when I hear what Hashem did to previous homosexuals. Sometimes I ask myself if Hashem hates me for loving women, and it's something I dread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Judaism think about homosexuality?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/what-does-judaism-think-about-homosexuality) which is not, in fact, only about men.

Comment: brachakantorovich, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thank you for bringing your questions here! I encourage you to take a look at [this "beginner's guide"](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/) to learn more about how Mi Yodeya works.

Comment: `All the men that I ever encountered in my life only thought about sex and women's assets and their own pleasure, even if they tried to hide it it would still be obvious. Have they ever thought about pure love or is selfish pleasure all what's in their mind?` I'm sorry that this has been your experience, but this is an overgeneralization.

Comment: [Maimonides, Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Issurei Biah 21](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960669/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twenty-One.htm):

Comment: Issac Moses and Double AA my question is not a duplicate of this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/what-does-judaism-think-about-homosexuality since I explicitly only asked what Judaism thinks about lesbians, not what Judaism thinks about homosexuality in general.

Comment: I don't think this part of the question is a duplicate: "I'm really curious as to why nothing has been said about it even though our sages (of blessed memory)".

Comment: @brachakantorovich, First, let me express sympathy for your personal struggles. I think that is much more important than any issues of site policy around here. But on the duplicate question, the rule in meta: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/closing-as-duplicate-of-broader-post is that a duplicate is a duplicate when it asks for a subset of the broader question that a good answer to the broader question would have answered. That is why this question was closed.

Comment: With a bit of focus, I think you could turn this into a good question that is probably not a duplicate. Instead you could focus on what and why there are differences in how the Torah (or the sages) focus on the two different types of homosexuality.

Comment: not duplicate, nashim mesolelot and male homosexuality is diffeend and general question about homosexuality is also different. @IsaacMoses can you examine this?

Comment: @kouty, feel free to comment/answer that point, about how a general question is different than a specific one, about this question or in general in meta.

Comment: @Yishai i am with a phone its not easy

Comment: To repeat @yishai 's sentiment, I and no doubt many others, are deeply sympathetic and wish you the greatest success in dealing with the difficulties that life has dealt you. Regarding your last comments, I encourage you to ignore over-dramatic rhetoric that you may have heard. Being dealt a certain set of challenges by God does not mean that He hates you. The Gemara Sanhedrin (44a) states that even A Jew who sins, which you have not done, is still considered a Jew. Don’t forget God’s eternal love with the Jewish people as Malachi 1:3 and Yirmiyah 31:19 remind us. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Rambam writes in Hilkhot Yesodei HaTorah (5:10) that a person who refrains from a sin for no personal benefit, but only because that is what God wants, performs the mitzvah of kiddush Hashem, even if no one else knows!

Comment: @kouty there is no indication in the other question that it's specifically about men. In addition, both questions, at least as far as I can tell, are about how Judaism relates to homosexual *feelings* and the people who have them, not to specific acts.

Comment: @IsaacMoses you are right.

Comment: @Yishai I agree that there are parts of this post that could possibly be developed into answerable questions that are distinct from the other one. I would recommend avoiding preservation of the potentially inflammatory editorializing and steering clear of requests for evaluation of the merits of any individuals.

Comment: @brachakantorovich to work out your own feelings, I recommend that you seek counsel from someone who is expert in the relevant aspects of Judaism and who either knows you personally or could come to know you. Mi Yodeya can't do that for you, though we can help find relevant information. I wish you God's help in navigating your difficulties.